# How to display and sort all Google+ posts based on most voted video/photo?

Tags: google-plus, sorting, google-plus-1

I would like to display all Google+ posts into my website and I would like to categorise them into:

1. most voted video/photo
2. most recent video/photo

How can I achieve the above? I know how to embed them individually, but I would like to retrieve all the posts and sort them.